# Filter tasks scheduled for the future in Taskwarrior

Tags: utilities, taskwarrior

My custom report in Taskwarrior is set to the following:

```
report.custom.filter=status:pending
```

I would like to change this so that tasks scheduled for the future are hidden until their start date. For example, instead of:

```
username@hostname:~% task custom
ID PROJECT           TAGS    DUE DESCRIPTION
 9 Reading           next        Read Gödel, Escher, Bach 
10 Social            waiting 4mo Wish Alice a happy birthday
```

in which task 10 has the property `scheduled:2018-01-01`, I would like instead to see:

```
username@hostname:~% task custom
ID PROJECT           TAGS    DUE DESCRIPTION
 9 Reading           next        Read Gödel, Escher, Bach
```

And then for task 10 to appear on 2018-01-01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `and +READY` to the filter.

```
report.custom.filter=status:pending and +READY
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the scheduled or waiting settings for this?

https://taskwarrior.org/docs/using_dates.html